# KVO listener issues in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, key-value-observing, nsobject

I am using `ViewModel` class and want to setup observer if any changes into `loginResponse` variable.

```
@objcMembers class ViewModel: NSObject {

    var count = 300
    @objc dynamic var loginResponse :String

    override init() {
        loginResponse = "1"
        super.init()
        setupTimer()
    }

    func setupTimer(){
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(callTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func callTimer(){
        let minutes = String(count / 60)
        let seconds = String(count % 60)
        loginResponse = minutes + ":" + seconds
        count =  count - 1
    }
}
```

View controller code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _ = viewModel.observe(\ViewModel.loginResponse) { (model, changes) in
        print(changes)
    }
}
```

I want to listen to any change into `loginResponse` variable in my Viewcontroller but it's not getting the callback. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need a strong reference to the observer. `_ =` is pointless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.observe(_:options:changeHandler:)` function returns a `NSKeyValueObservation` object that is used to control the lifetime of the observation. When it is deinited or invalidated, the observation will stop.

Since your view controller doesn't keep a reference to the returned "observation" it goes out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad` and thus stops observing.

To continue observing for the lifetime of the view controller, store the returned observation in a property. If you're "done" observing before that, you can call `invalidate` on the observation or set the property to `nil`.