# Swift 4 switch to new observe API

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift4, avplayer, key-value-observing

I am having trouble with the new `observe` API in Swift 4.

```
player = AVPlayer()
player?.observe(\.currentItem.status, options: [.new], changeHandler: { [weak self] (player, newValue) in
    if let status = AVPlayer.Status(rawValue: (newValue as! NSNumber).intValue) {

   }
 }
```

But I get an error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

How do I fix it? Not sure about `keyPath` syntax.

There is also a warning in extracting AVPlayerStatus in the closure above

> Cast from 'NSKeyValueObservedChange' to unrelated type 'NSNumber' always fails"

Comment: You probably want to save the returned `NSKeyValueObservation` token...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`currentItem` is an *optional* property of `AVPlayer`. The following compiles
in Swift 4.2/Xcode 10 (note the additional question mark in the key path):

```
let observer = player.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: [.new]) {
    (player, change) in
    guard let optStatus = change.newValue else {
        return // No new value provided by observer
    }
    if let status = optStatus {
        // `status` is the new status, type is `AVPlayerItem.Status`
    } else {
        // New status is `nil`
    }
}
```

The observed property is an optional `AVPlayer.Status?`, therefore
 `change.newValue` inside the callback is a “double optional” `AVPlayer.Status??` and must be unwrapped twice.

It may fail to compile in older Swift versions, compare
[Swift’s ‘observe()’ doesn’t work for key paths with optionals?](https://forums.swift.org/t/swifts-observe-doesnt-work-for-key-paths-with-optionals/6366) in the Swift forum.

Comment: There is a warning as well when I try to extract status. Please suggest what is wrong.

Comment: @DeepakSharma: `newValue` is not a NSNumber. See update.

Comment: Ok, final question. How do we remove this observer later. Just setting returned statusObserver = nil?

Comment: @DeepakSharma: From the Quick Help: *"when the returned NSKeyValueObservation is deinited or invalidated, it will stop observing."* See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591915/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216154/1187415

Comment: I tried it. Does not work, always returns nil values. old API still work. Something is wrong. I thought it worked but upon putting breakpoints, only get nil values.

Comment: Your answer may be correct but it may be bug in Swift https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5872

Comment: @DeepakSharma: I must admit that I checked only that it compiles, not if it actually works.

Comment: Which means there is no way to switch for the time being. Swift sucks, language still evolves and keeps changing with bugs.

Comment: where is documentation for `player.observe(..)?` and what is this backslash syntax ` player.observe(\.currentItem.status`)? i never saw it.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz: This might be a good starting point: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the player instance instead of the change(NSKeyValueObservedChange) from the closure to get what you need.

```
//Declare observation token at class level for managing the observation lifetime.

    var kvoToken: NSKeyValueObservation?

//Add your observer

    kvoToken = player.observe(\.currentItem?.status) { (player, _) in
                switch player.currentItem?.status {
                case.readyToPlay:
                    print("Ready to play")
                case .failed:
                    print("failed")
                case .unknown:
                    print("unknown")
                default:
                    print("deafult")
                }
            }

//In deinit, invalidate the token.

    deinit {
        kvoToken?.invalidate()
    }
```